# SQL Server to VB.Net IF EXISTS needs to return anything, but doesn't

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have this:

```
IF EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1
    FROM User_Passwords
    WHERE up_Password = @CurrentPassword)
    PRINT 'Bad Password'
    --RETURN TRUE
ELSE
```

From what I'm running into, I need my SP to return something, a 1 or 0, or a string/varchar, so I can do some work on the VB side.  But as of right now, it's not returning anything, unless I'm not calling it correctly.  This is the VB code:

```
Public Function UpdatePasswords()

    Dim objCommand As New SqlCommand("Update_Passwords", DatabaseInterface_.Connection)
    objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ua_pk", ua_pk_)
    objCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@ResetDaysAmount", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, .Value = Company.GetSetting("PasswordExpireDays", SettingMisc.ReturnDataType.Integer_)})
    objCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@AllowedNumberOfPasswords", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, .Value = Company.GetSetting("NumberOfPasswords", SettingMisc.ReturnDataType.Integer_)})
    objCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@CurrentPasswordDate", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date, .Value = ua_PasswordDate_})
    objCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@CurrentPassword", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Value = ua_Password_})

    If objCommand.ExecuteScalar.ToString() = "Bad Password" Or 1 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Instead of doing an exist you can do it in one call instead of doing the exist and then doing a select....

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return something to your code using the SELECT statement

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM User_Passwords WHERE up_Password = @CurrentPassword)
    SELECT 1
ELSE
    SELECT 0
```

And then your code is

```
Dim result = Convert.ToInt32(objCommand.ExecuteScalar())
Return If(result = 1, True, False)
```

Comment: I was getting super frustrated.  I couldn't think straight.  THANK YOU!  You saved my brain and anger

Comment: This isn't working as I had hoped.  It's not returning a 1 when the Currentpassword = any of the passwords in the table.

Comment: Well you have totally changed the original question.Now it is a lot more complex than symply asking if a record exists or not. Now the problem lies somewhere else in your huge stored procedure. And before the point where you reach the IF EXISTS. I can see a lot of deletes and I cannot understand what's going on there sorry, but perhaps you should ask a new question and not reopening an old one

Comment: okay sounds good, i'll take the edit off and run a new question. Thank you