# IF EXISTS then ELSE with INSERT, SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

My previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174488/sql-server-to-vb-net-if-exists-needs-to-return-anything-but-doesnt) ended up not answering my long term question, which is this:

I need to compare the `User_Passwords` password (`up_Password`) to the incoming, new password (`@CurrentPassword`).  If they match, I need to return a `1` so the code follows a different track, while if it's a new password, it will be `INSERTed` into the table.  This is the section of my stored procedure that I THINK is acting up:

```
DECLARE @UserNumberOfPasswords INT
DECLARE @ua_pk uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @ResetDaysAmount INT
DECLARE @AllowedNumberOfPasswords INT
DECLARE @CurrentPasswordDate DATE
DECLARE @CurrentPassword varchar(25)

SELECT *
FROM dbo.User_Passwords
WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk
ORDER BY up_PasswordDate DESC

DELETE FROM User_Passwords
WHERE @ua_pk = ua_fk
AND @CurrentPasswordDate > (DATEADD(DAY, (@ResetDaysAmount - 1), up_PasswordDate))

SELECT *
FROM dbo.User_Passwords
WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk
ORDER BY up_PasswordDate ASC

SELECT @UserNumberOfPasswords = COUNT(*)    
FROM User_Passwords AS up
WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk

IF @UserNumberOfPasswords > @AllowedNumberOfPasswords
BEGIN
    WITH T
    AS (SELECT TOP (@UserNumberOfPasswords - @AllowedNumberOfPasswords) *
        FROM   User_Passwords
        WHERE  ua_fk = @ua_pk
        ORDER BY up_PasswordDate ASC)
    DELETE FROM T; 
END

IF @UserNumberOfPasswords = @AllowedNumberOfPasswords
BEGIN
    WITH T
    AS (SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM User_Passwords
        WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk
        ORDER BY up_PasswordDate ASC)
    DELETE FROM T;
END

IF EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1
    FROM User_Passwords
    WHERE up_Password = @CurrentPassword)
    SELECT 1
ELSE
    INSERT INTO User_Passwords (ua_fk, up_Password, up_PasswordDate)
    VALUES (@ua_pk, @CurrentPassword, @CurrentPasswordDate
```

I have done lots of testing, and the conclusion I'm getting to is that this will always return a `1` and I'm not completely sure why.

Bottom line - I want to compare values, if the values do equal, go back to VB.Net with a value so I can use that for a different route of code, while if they do not equal, I'll add it to the table then return back to my VB.Net code.

Comment: Well, for one, you're just blanket checking the password against the table with no regard to the user you're looking it up for.

Comment: i have that in my full SP.

Comment: this is just a code piece

Comment: Then show your full, actual query.  Because as written, this exists statement will always come back true if the password passed in matches *anyones* password in the table, regardless of who the user requesting it is (regardless of whatever you might not have included earlier in the procedure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
IF EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1
    FROM User_Passwords
    WHERE up_Password = @CurrentPassword)
    SELECT 1
ELSE
    INSERT INTO User_Passwords (ua_fk, up_Password, up_PasswordDate)
    VALUES (@ua_pk, @CurrentPassword, @CurrentPasswordDate
```

Shouldn't it be

```
IF EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1
    FROM User_Passwords
    WHERE up_Password = @CurrentPassword
    AND   ua_fk = @ua_pk ) //Only search for passwords that belong to this user
    SELECT 1
ELSE
    INSERT INTO User_Passwords (ua_fk, up_Password, up_PasswordDate)
    VALUES (@ua_pk, @CurrentPassword, @CurrentPasswordDate
```

...?

Otherwise the stored procedure will return 1 if the password exists for any user (not just the user of interest), which might explain your results.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @result integer;   

IF EXISTS         (SELECT 1
                   FROM User_Passwords
                   WHERE up_Password = @CurrentPassword)
  BEGIN
    SET @result = 1;
  END;
ELSE
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO User_Passwords (ua_fk, up_Password, up_PasswordDate)
    VALUES (@ua_pk, @CurrentPassword, @CurrentPasswordDate);
    SET @result = 0;
 END;

RETURN @result;
```

Comment: try again. Forgot the `SET`

Comment: "A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context."

Comment: Well depend on your store procedure, in this case I was assuming you return integer

Comment: Maybe you should go and read the manual about SP, why you have a SELECT and didnt store the result?

Comment: I cant teach you how create a SP. Go read the manual, start with a small sample and start adding things.

Comment: i've written this one from scratch. thought i was doing pretty well.  mind pointing me in the right direction.  this isn't for school, this is for work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130981/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-kevin-fischer).

Answer (score 0):

I normally add a print if I need more to debug

```
IF EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1
    FROM User_Passwords
    WHERE up_Password = @CurrentPassword)
    BEGIN
        PRINT ('EXISTS')
        PRINT ('up_Password:' + up_Password)
        PRINT ('@CurrentPassword:' + @CurrentPassword)
    SELECT 1
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT ('NOT EXISTS')
        PRINT ('up_Password:' + up_Password)
        PRINT ('@CurrentPassword:' + @CurrentPassword)
        INSERT INTO User_Passwords (ua_fk, up_Password, up_PasswordDate)
        VALUES (@ua_pk, @CurrentPassword, @CurrentPasswordDate)
    END
```